ML Modelling advice where a feature is partially missing but highly informative when present
I am building a model to predict a customer purchase event on a website. Specifically for those customers who, overnight when the model is run, have not yet purchased. Prediction is important, but feature insight is just as key.
I'm collecting basic data about the customer (e.g. device, rough location), details of their clicks such as referrer and marketing sources, pages visited, and deriving some features myself from e.g. timestamps, most notably "time since last visit".

Edited here for additional information as per request ---
Time since last visit is a rolling total of time since a customer was last seen on the site.
Where a customer purchases, we capture the time between their last two visits, and we use that as a training feature.  Typically we see that a short period between last two visits is more likely to lead to purchase (customer is more engaged), but we do see a reasonably broad range of values.
Where a customer does not purchase, we just track how long it is since their last visit. What we see here is that these times span a short window (model looks at the above positive cases, and upweights their chances), through to a long time-since window - past when we normally see conversion cases - and so their chances are downweighted.
The missing data occurs when a customer visits once and purchases there and then.  They don't have time between last two visits (it's zero, or NA).  In terms of training the model, it doesn't make sense to record how long since they purchased because the event has already happened. The field entry is therefore set to missing.
Edit end  ----

My dilemma is this:
During training, "time since last visit" becomes a hugely significant indicator in purchase for those customers we see more than once.  These customers are in the minority however (30%)
However, those that visit only once and purchase immediately do not have a "time since last seen" value as they've completed their journey with TimeSince = NA (or zero if you like).
If I build a model on just customers visiting 2 or more times (so I have this "time since"), then I'm leaving a lot of insight on the table from those 1-time customers.
However, if I build a model to include 1-time visitors then my model picks up the TimeSince=NA as leaky data indicating purchase, which then skews the model and accuracy metrics.
I'm after suggestions please?
The ideal model for me would just "ignore" that field where it is NA, but use it where I have values. But I'm currently using XGB and that's not how tree models work! NAs get treated as a discrete value and pushed in to a branch.
My first question:  Are there any other classifier models out there that can selectively use a field only where populated?
The other idea I had was some kind of ensemble. A model with everyone in but without this time-since field so it can't leak, a second one WITH the field but for visitors with 2+ visits only... and then some kind of combination of these afterwards.
I'm struggling a bit with this idea as then the insight piece becomes more complex to pull out, and whether this is in general the best route.
Thanks!

this sounds like something else is wrong? why dont you have people who visit only once and dont purchase?

I do have those people. When I'm training on the data overnight, I have a time since last seen for those we didn't see purchase (the ones you're talking about I think). But for those that did purchase, they've completed their journey and we don't expect to see them again, hence it's zero/NA.

I still don't understand. maybe you can add to your question the actual range of possibilities ( buy/dont buy & time to last visit).It feels like your mappings are inconsistent, eg time since last purchase should be as of view (before purchase), then there would be no information leakage. is it that you are only modelling customers and not visitors?

I've tried to add that extra detail.  The data is consistent, and it's in line with what you've said I think.
